# how to connect my eclipse to microsoft sql server management studio express edition?

Tags: java, sql-server, myeclipse

I am trying to connect my eclipse to sql server managment studio, i have added an external jar " sqljdbc4.jar "to the libraries of my project, and i added the VM argument :

"-Djava.library.path = "C:\Users\toshiba\Downloads\Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server\sqljdbc_4.0\enu\auth\x64“"

when i run the project i get the error :
Error: Could not find or load main class =

is there any solution for this error? or can i get other solution to connect my eclipse to sql server management studio express edition and thankou

Comment: "C:\Users\toshiba\Downloads\Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server\sqljdbc_4.0\enu\auth\x64“"

Does this file exist on the path? Is the path correct? Is the path set in system variables correctly?

Comment: please paste that code snippet where you connect to the database. Also try pasting the class in a folder with a shorter path preferably with no spaces. Have u added the jar to the Build Path? this forum post might be useful: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/3587/

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, is this to do with MyEclipse or just eclipse (the question has a "myeclipse" tag, but it's not clear that you are using MyEclipse)?

The JDBC driver needs to be on the classpath, not the java.library.path, which is for native libraries. Add the jar file, containing the JDBC driver to your build path.

For help with MyEclipse functions (e.g. the database explorer), you will need to post a lot more detail about what you're doing. For example, it's possible to add hibernate or jpa to your project and connect it to your chosen database but I'm not sure if you're using those facets.